# I want to create a project with vaadin and spring with out eclipse plugin

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

I want to create a Project on Vaadin along with Spring and Hibernate. I can't find the proper steps to create it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a project by using [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) and make sure that you select Vaadin as a dependency on the page. The generated zip file contains a working Spring Boot Maven or Gradle project, and you can run it by executing the Java class containing a standard Java `main` method. When the you run the the main method, an embedded tomcat is running at http://localhost:8080.

If you included Vaadin into the project at the Spring Initializer web page, you have correct Vaadin dependencies on your project and the only thing you need to do, is to add a Vaadin UI to the project. For example:

```
@com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI
class MyUI extends com.vaadin.ui.UI {

  @Override
  protected void init(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest request) {
    setContent(new com.vaadin.ui.Label("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Now this Vaadin UI is available at http://localhost:8080.

To include Hibernate to the project, you just need to check the JPA checkbox.